# WP7 Listbox - clearing selected item

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selecteditem

I am using a listbox in a data template - and from an earlier post I cannot reference the listbox directly in the code behind.

As a result I am capturing the last selected object in the selectionchanged event for the listbox and using this when I want to navigate.

I now need to also  clear the selected object in the listbox -can I do this in the selectionchanged event (after storing it away).

Alternatively I could use the MouseLeftButtonDown event on the listbox (which I understand is the equivalent of a 'click') but can I get  the selected object in the listbox in this event.

- thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the selection changed event set `<ListboxName>.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Also, do not use the MouseLeftButtonDown event. This will fire whenever the user touches the ListBox, even if they're just trying to scroll up / down and not actually selecting an item.

Comment: Unfortunately the listbox is defined within a data template and so I don't seem to have the ability to reference it in the code behind.  The listbox is passed in as an argument into the selectionchanged event I think (object sender) - can I cast this to a list box and clear it that way.  I am not sure of the syntax required to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can cast it. Pratorians example can be extended like this: (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the SelectedIndex in code behind then, instead of detecting the SelectionChanged event you could detect a `Tap` event on the ListBoxItem.